# Can Bob be convicted by the US for viewing fictional child pornography hosted by a US site while viewing it in a non-US country?

Tags: united-states, extraterritorial-jurisdiction, child-porn

The wording on the relevant legal literature confuses me. According to 18 US Code 2252:

> Any person who..

> (2) knowingly receives, or distributes, any visual depiction using any means or facility of interstate or foreign commerce or that has been mailed, or has been shipped or transported in or affecting interstate or foreign commerce, or which contains materials which have been mailed or so shipped or transported, by any means including by computer, or knowingly reproduces any visual depiction for distribution using any means or facility of interstate or foreign commerce or in or affecting interstate or foreign commerce or through the mails, if—
> (A) the producing of such visual depiction involves the use of a minor engaging in sexually explicit conduct; and
> (B) such visual depiction is of such conduct;

Yet, according to [this..](https://www.justice.gov/criminal-ceos/citizens-guide-us-federal-law-extraterritorial-sexual-exploitation-children)

> There are also some child pornography laws that apply to conduct overseas. Sections 2251(c) and 2260(a) of Title 18, United States Code both make it a crime for anyone to produce child pornography in foreign countries if they import the child abuse images into the United States, or if they intend to do so.  The penalty for a first time offender under these statutes is at least 15 years, up to a maximum of 30 years in prison.

I can’t seem to figure out then if Bob has committed a crime in the US. He likely isn’t culpable from the quote above due to not producing anything (and what he viewed was an obscene visual depiction, not real child porn), but by viewing the image that has its website hosted in the US even though he viewed it in a foreign country, has he participated in the “foreign commerce” incriminating under 18 US Code 2252?

**Update**

I have just been made aware about [18 US Code 1466A](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1466A). Would Bob be found guilty under this statute? To my knowledge, the answer will be no as 18 USC § 1466 only applies extraterritorially to the special maritime and territorial jurisdiction, so not a foreign country, but I’d like to hear some takes on this.

Comment: Is Bob a US citizens? (There are some situations where the USA will prosecute US citizens for actions abroad where they wouldn't prosecute non-citizens for the same actions abroad).

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

It does not appear that Bob has committed a U.S. crime.

**Long Answer**

18 USC § 2252(2) quoted in the OP does not apply because the question states that the material does not fit the definition of child pornography in that statute (unless the federal government can establish that the visual depiction was drawn or painted, rather than photographed or video recorded, from children engaged in sexually explicit conduct).

The territorial application of 18 USC § 2252(2) in cases where actual child pornography as defined in the statute is transmitted is arguably applicable. The general rule is that a crime can be prosecuted where it is committed, or where it has an effect. If a child victim were U.S. based, the crime committed by Bob abroad would arguably have been committed, in part, in the U.S. But, there is also a presumption that U.S. criminal laws do not have extraterritorial application unless their terms clearly show a contrary intent, which isn't terribly clear here (although I haven't seen a case directly on point).

18 USC §§ 2251(c) and 2260(a) also do not apply because the content is being exported from the U.S., not imported to the U.S., so even if it was child pornography, it wouldn't be within the scope of those offenses.

I have not scoured Title 18 for other offenses that could conceivably be implicated.

**UPDATE:**

> To my knowledge, the answer will be no as 18 USC § 1466[A] only applies
> extraterritorially to the special maritime and territorial
> jurisdiction, so not a foreign country, but I’d like to hear some
> takes on this.

I do not have an affirmative answer to this question. It would take more time to research and evaluate than my interest in extraterritorial application of U.S. child pornography can support at the moment.

However, the conclusion in the quoted material above is not supported by the statutory language. The pertinent part of Section 1466A (i.e. 18 U.S.C. § 1466A(d)) has five subsections connected by the word "or". Specifically this states (emphasis added):

> (d)Circumstances.—The circumstance referred to in subsections (a) and
> (b) is that—
>
> (1)any communication involved in or made in furtherance of the offense
> is communicated or transported by the mail, or in interstate or
> foreign commerce by any means, including by computer, or any means or
> instrumentality of interstate or foreign commerce is otherwise used in
> committing or in furtherance of the commission of the offense;
>
> (2)any communication involved in or made in furtherance of the offense
> contemplates the transmission or transportation of a visual depiction
> by the mail, or in interstate or foreign commerce by any means,
> including by computer;
>
> (3)any person travels or is transported in interstate or foreign
> commerce in the course of the commission or in furtherance of the
> commission of the offense;
>
> (4)any visual depiction involved in the offense has been mailed, or
> has been shipped or transported in interstate or foreign commerce by
> any means, including by computer, or was produced using materials that
> have been mailed, or that have been shipped or transported in
> interstate or foreign commerce by any means, including by computer;
> **or**
>
> (5)the offense is committed in the special maritime and territorial
> jurisdiction of the United States or in any territory or possession of
> the United States.

Thus, only one of those five parts of that subsection must be present for the statute to apply. A location in the special maritime and territorial jurisdiction of the United States (which is not, strictly speaking, extraterritorial anyway, this is just a special subset of U.S. territory outside any U.S. state or the District of Columbia), is sufficient to bring the statute into play, but is not the only way that it can be implicated. Any of the other four parts of that subsection could also trigger the application of the statute.

The statute does not expressly state whether it has extraterritorial application on its face, so one is left trying to weigh the presumption that U.S. criminal laws do not have extraterritorial application unless they say otherwise, against the language specifically contemplating the use of "foreign commerce" in a way that doesn't unambiguously treat importing and exporting regulated material differently.

Also, because the statute does not require that the depiction be of an actual instance of a child engaging in sexually explicit conduct, the default criminal jurisdictional analysis over whether either the criminal act, or the consequences of the criminal act took place in the U.S. is less clear.

Further, there are issues over whether a visual depiction that did not involve an actual minor is indeed constitutional under the First Amendment.

Each of these case law driven considerations is weighty and the subject to a significant body of complicated to apply case law that isn't perfectly consistent internally, so it is quite challenging to determine as a matter of law whether this law would apply to Bob in this fact pattern, unless there is an almost identical case that has squarely addressed this fact pattern and isn't implicitly repealed by later decisions of higher courts.

So, I can't answer how this question would be resolved legally one way or the other with any confidence at this point and I am not willing to do the substantial additional research that would be necessary to make this determination (which would probably reach the conclusion that there is not a definitive answer in the law at this time).

Comment: I’m asking if it appeared on his computer screen in a foreign country - not the US. If it, an image hosted by a US website, appeared on Bob’s laptop while he and his laptop were in a country that is not the US, like France.

Comment: O.K., my apologies, I misread the question and thought you were talking about exactly the opposite fact pattern. I will look at it again in that light when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks for editing. So obscene visual depictions (cartoons) of minors are not applicable under the territorial application 18 USC § 2252 (2) but real child pornography is? Why is that? I’m confused about the part where you wrote “(unless the federal government can establish that the visual depiction was drawn or painted, rather than photographed or video recorded, from children engaged in sexually explicit conduct)”. Also, reception or distribution by foreign commerce excludes things that are exported *from* the United States by 18 USC §§ 2251(c) and 2260(a)? How do you know this?

Comment: To be clear, Bob viewed drawings depicting children engaging in sexually explicit conduct from France

Comment: @walstack If cartoons are produced by a method that involves observing live child models engage in sexually explicit conduct, then they are still covered. The justification is to prevent a process of child porn creation that necessarily involved rape, akin to bans on conflict diamonds, rather than a limitation on content per se.

Comment: "Also, reception or distribution by foreign commerce excludes things that are exported from the United States by 18 USC §§ 2251(c) and 2260(a)? How do you know this?" The quoted material in the OP says something that is equivalent to that statement.

Comment: So it is *not* covered if the production did not involve live children in any way? I think that’s clear from (A) from 18 USC § 2252(2) but I don’t understand what is meant in (B) by “such visual depiction is of such conduct”. I don’t know what is meant by “such conduct”.

Comment: (B) means that if you rape all of your child actors in their auditions and then have them give fully clothed non-sexual monologs on TV that the resulting work isn't child porn.

Comment: “The quoted material in the OP says something that is equivalent to that statement” So “foreign commerce” implies things that are imported to the US from a foreign country, and *not* things that are imported to another country from the USA? I’m not sure where that’s implied, but I’m ignorant on this matter.

Comment: @walstack In this context, "imported" means "imported to the U.S."

Comment: Apologies for not entirely understanding you yet. I suppose I will accept that “foreign commerce” is well understood as something imported to the US from another country and strictly not the other way around. However, I still don’t understand your explanation of (B). Can you tell me what “such conduct” means in perhaps a different way?

Comment: @walstrack (A) prohibits sexually abusing child actors. (B) says that sexual abuse of child actors is only relevant when images of the abuse of child actors shows up in the final product. It isn't "foreign commerce" that is particular to being imported. Foreign commerce can go both ways. But those particular statutes only apply extraterritorially to foreign imports to the U.S. in foreign commerce.

Comment: I see. In regards to the quote “Those particular statutes only apply extraterritorially to foreign imports to the U.S. in foreign commerce” where is this written/how do you know this is true?

Comment: @walstack The material you quote in the OP says so: "Sections 2251(c) and 2260(a) of Title 18, United States Code both make it a crime for anyone to produce child pornography in foreign countries if they import the child abuse images into the United States, or if they intend to do so."

Comment: but they’re referencing 2251(c) and 2260(a) in that quote, not 2252(2).

Comment: I am too. My reference to "importing" is strictly limited to those two sections.

Comment: I think I get it  - I was preoccupied by the “foreign commerce” wording in 2252(2), but regardless of what that wording entails, you’re saying since the material does not fit the definition of child porn in that statute, it isn’t applicable anyway. And I clearly understand why 2251(c) and 2260(a) are inapplicable due to this being an export from the US. However, I’m still confused why cartoon child pornography doesn’t fit the description of a visual depiction “of such conduct”. It still appears to me that “such conduct” refers to merely “sexually explicit conduct”. Not sure how it’s a misread?

Comment: It the cartoon pornography depicts drawings of what appears to be underage fictional persons having sex, I don’t see how it’s not “of such [sexually explicit] conduct”, but I’m really having trouble making sense of it. Sorry for such a long drawn out dialogue by the way.

Comment: I understand now. (A) and (B) must both apply for 2252(2) to apply, and (A) cannot apply for a cartoon drawing made by an artist with no children directly involved. Do I have that right?

Comment: in regards to your update, this link seems to imply that 1466A enjoys “express extraterritorial application” in the special maritime and territorial jurisdiction, and beyond that mentions nothing: https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/94-166.pdf